# Do CMD FINDSTR STRING AND COPY FILE

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with subfolders include txt and pdf files. There is a Pdf file for each txt file which has nearly same name.

For example; for each **ABC_R10.txt**  --> there is a **ABC).pdf** file.

In Windows 10, with a batch file,

I want to search specific string in a .txt file with FINDSTR command, and copy files, which contain my string, into current folder. I achieved proper code until this point.

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
ECHO FIND BUKUM

findstr /m /s /i /p /c:"BUKUM" *.txt > logfile.xls

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m /s /i /p /c:"BUKUM" *.txt') do ^
copy "%%a" "%cd%" 


if errorlevel 1 echo nothing found.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

But I want to find file name of exact match but get pdf file with similar name, not txt file.

I have to get **ABC** of **ABC_R10.txt** and add **).pdf** string and get **ABC).pdf**

Substring of **_R** occurs each .txt file.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: First you should show your code. If iterating the .txt file with a for variable use the modifier `%%~nA` for example to return the name without extension and append your `.pdf` extension instead.

Comment: I edited post with code included. I'm trying your suggestion right now.

Comment: Changing the scope of your question isn't fair when there is already an answer that does solve your original question. Reason: The answer is now invalid, which will lead to downvotes to the answer (which doesn't deserve it, because it answered your original question) If you have to change the scope of your question, it's better to ask a follow-up question (and add a link to this one for reference). (PS: as long as there is no answer yet, changing your question is not a problem)

Comment: You are right. It is my mistake because of I posted from phone without certainity of question. 

I'm going to follow your suggestion next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based solely on your now edited question:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=_" %%A In ('FindStr /SPMIC:"BUKUM" *.txt') Do @Copy /Y "%%A).pdf">Nul
```

Comment: Is there a way to just copy all filenames that are similar regardless of the file extension. Example 123.pdf & 123 (2).pdf.

Comment: I'm not sure how your question is related to the question this solved. Unless you can explain it's relevance, very succinctly in a return comment, with sufficient detail for an answer, I'd suggest you submit a new question of your own.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: there is nothing to say to @Compo's  modification,**
just when using the `)` unquoted inside a code block it has to be escpaped `^)`

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO FIND BUKUM
for /f "delims=_" %%A in (
  'findstr /msip /c:"BUKUM" *.txt'
) do if exist "%%A).pdf" (
  copy "%%A).pdf" "%cd%" 
  Echo copied %%A^).pdf to %cd%
) else echo not found "%%A).pdf"
PAUSE
```