# Find filename with FINDSTR that start with 'abc...' and not '-abc...'

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a folder with subfolders, which include files.

In Windows 10, with a batch file,

I want to search specific string in a .txt file with FINDSTR command, and copy files, which contain my string, into current folder.

```
REM Adjust location of list
SET list=C:\WorkProjects\Experiment\list.txt

REM Source dir
SET source=Z:\

REM Target dir
SET destination=C:\WorkProjects\Experiment

SET logfile=Outcome2.log

cd /d "%source%">>"%destination%\%directoryfile%"
dir * /s/b | FINDSTR /I /R /C:".*.pdf">"%destination%\%directoryfile%"

ECHO 2>"%destination%\temp.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%A IN (%list%) DO (
    ECHO %%A>>"%destination%\temp.txt"
    For /F "Delims=" %%X In ('FINDSTR /I /R /C:"\<%%A\..*\>" "%destination%\%logfile%"') DO (
    ECHO %%X>>"%destination%\temp.txt"
    )
)
```

`%list%` contains a list of strings as depicted below *depicted below*:

```
12345
abcdf
aadfe
```

Here is the output of the example:

12345 **<-- This is the string that I am looking for**

Z:\Master List\1\12\123\1234\12345.pdf **<-- Output**

Z:\Master List\A\AD\AD-1\AD-12\AD-12345.pdf **<-- Output**

So, the first path is what I want it to return and the second path isn't because it has "AD-" in the front of it.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows CMD FINDSTR STRING AND COPY FILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452100/windows-cmd-findstr-string-and-copy-file)

Comment: What about using as regular expression search string `"\\%%A\.[^\\]*$"`? Run in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) `findstr /?` for help on this expression.

Comment: I would suggest that you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59413166/edit) to include code that we can replicate, _(we have no idea what any of your variables represent, what the content of `%list%` looks like, or exactly what you're trying to isolate from that content)_. If we cannot replicate your environment and code with known content in a similar environment to yours, we have to guess, and guessing isn't what technical sites do.

Comment: @T3RR0R, that link doesn't solve this question.  I am trying to achieve a search on "\<abc\..*\>", which to me is that its a string starting with "abc" and **NOT** "cd-abc"

Comment: The string itself is not particularly relevent- your question regards using findstring to copy files using the result. The answer linked Regards the same.

The means by which to resolve your problem exists, however will need adapting for the string/s you wish to operate your For Loop on.

If your question is asking for the exact code to do your task, please, reword it, and perhaps someone will do your coding for you.

Comment: I know the string isn't relevant, my question is do I try to use another command or how I could modify the  `For /F "Delims=" %%X In ('FINDSTR /I /R /C:"\<%%A\..*\>" "%destination%\%logfile%"')` so the filename starts with 'abc' and 'abc' is NOT contained in the string.  The problem seems to be around the '-' character, because it doesn't return a string such as 'aabc'.

Comment: Taking the example string, `12345`, what you should be searching for with `FindStr`, to capture your file path, is any string with an ending matching `\12345.pdf`. _(`.pdf` is already known/guaranteed by your previous `Dir` and `FindStr` sequence)_. If you take a look at the usage information for the command, it should be very simple. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?` to read its usage information and available options.

Comment: well apparently it isn't so simple. I took  `/I /R /C:"\<%%A\..*\>"`, /I is Case-insensitive search, /R /C:_string_ Use _string_ as a regular expression. Which my _string_ is expressed as "\<%%A\..*\>, which if the variable `%%A` was `12345`, by definition I am searching for strings that begin with `12345` followed by a '.' _period_, then some extension

Comment: @BeauReed, your search string is the issue, not the methodology I've suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this:

```
dir * | findstr "12345"
```

You find:

```
12345.txt
AD-12345.txt
```

If you would base your script on the following:

```
dir 12345.*
```

You'd find:

```
 12345.txt
```

The `AD-12345` would not be found.

Comment: I am making a directory listing of all files to do a search on in

`dir * /s/b | FINDSTR /I /R /C:".*.pdf">"%destination%\%directoryfile%"`

Comment: @BeauReed, it seems as if you're suggesting that `%list%` in your code, should really be `%destination%\%directoryfile%`, is that true?

Comment: `%list%` is a list.txt that contains all the strings I want to find. `%destination%\%directoryfile%` is a directoryfile.txt file that contains the path of all files within `%source%`, which in this case I changed to the 'Z:\' drive.

Answer (score 0):

change `'FINDSTR /I /R /C:"\<%%A\..*\>"` to `'FINDSTR /I /R /C:"\\%%A\..*\>"` did the trick

Comment: it should be `"\\%%A\..*$"`, as the dot is a wildcard for "any character", you have to use `\.` for a literal dot. And better use `$` as "End of line"

Comment: And as I've already mentioned, you already know it's a `.pdf` extension, so why not say so directly, `FindStr /IRC:"\\%%A\.pdf$"`